# Custom MVC View implementation not rendering in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Within a Spring Boot 1.3.0 app I'm attempting to use a single controller method to generate both HTML and CSV-formatted responses based on the path alone (no Content-Negotiation):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class ReportController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "report.{fileExt}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String report(@PathVariable String fileExt, Model model) {
       // add stuff to the Model instance
       return fileExt + "Report";
    }
}
```

To handle the HTML formatting, I have a `src\resources\templates\htmlReport.tpl` Groovy Template. Spring Boot is able to locate and invoke the template just fine when I visit /app/report.html.

To handle the CSV formatting, I have a custom View:

```
@Component
public class ReportCsvView extends AbstractView {

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "text/csv";
    }

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        // write CSV to writer
    } 
}
```

And a custom ViewResolver to register my custom View

```
@Configuration
public class ReportCsvViewConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ReportCsvView reportCsvView;

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.viewResolver(new ViewResolver() {
            @Override
            public View resolveViewName(String name, Locale locale) throws Exception {
                return "csvReport".equals(name) ? reportCsvView : null;
            }
        });
        super.configureViewResolvers(registry);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when when I hit /app/report.csv, the anonymous ViewResolver's `resolveViewName` method is called, and the branch which returns the `ReportCsvView` instance is taken. So far so good. However, the `renderMergedOutputModel` is not called (although the `getContentType` method is called twice), resulting in an HTTP 404 response.

How do I get my View to actually render?

**UPDATE** I removed the overriding of the `getContentType` method; as a result, the `renderMergeOutputModel` is now getting called.